# Android QN: Change color of paint without affect previously drawn lines

Tags: android, colors, paint

I want to create a drawing application that allows user to draw with different colors. I am able to come up with everything except for the changing of colors.

I have a initial red paint to draw a few lines, and when i change the color to green, all the previously drawn lines are changed. I want the previously drawn lines to retain its red and new lines to be drawn with in green.

```
    canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
```

I use a canvas.drawPath  method to draw with, together with the mPaint paint. but when I change the mPaint color, everything changes color too.

I have tried to look through the web but could not find anything and I spent a really long time to figure it out already. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code in your Main class, it will be very helpful to you

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(new MyView(this));

mPaint = new Paint();
mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
mPaint.setDither(true);
mPaint.setColor(0xFFFF0000);
mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
mPaint.setStrokeWidth(3);
 }
 private Paint mPaint;
 private MaskFilter mEmboss;
 private MaskFilter mBlur;
 public void colorChanged(int color) {
 mPaint.setColor(color);
 }
```

Comment: How would I apply this with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18521661/change-color-without-affecting-anything-previously-drawn

Answer (score 0):

Why not just switch to a new paint rather than changing the color of the existing paint?

Comment: How would I switch to the new paint?

Comment: Creation of Paint objects is expensive performance wise. Switching to another pre-made Paint object does not seem to have an effect either