# Change color without affecting anything previously drawn

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

I have the following `CustomView` I am using for painting in my app:

```
package com.test.testing;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.Paint.Style;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomView extends TextView {
    Paint paint;
    Path path;
    float x = 0;
    float y = 0;
    private int cWhite = Color.WHITE;

    public CustomView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        paint = new Paint();
        path= new Path();
        paint.setAlpha(255);
        paint.setColor(cWhite);
        paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(20);
    }

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawPath(path,paint);
        canvas.drawCircle(x, y, 10, paint);
    }

    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        int action = event.getAction();
        switch (action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            path.moveTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
            path.lineTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            x = event.getX();
            y = event.getY();
            path.lineTo(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            path.lineTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

I setup a `FrameLayout` which keeps the canvas for drawing in my XML:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/viewd"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</FrameLayout>
```

I call inside my `Activity` to get the view to enable the user to draw on:

```
layout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.viewd);
//layout.removeAllViews();
view = new CustomView(Activity.this);
view.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
layout.addView(view);
```

I have different color option that user can choose from to change the paint stroke color in a `Dialog` within my `Activity`:

```
public void colorHandle() {
    // custom dialog
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.colorlayout);
    dialog.setTitle("Choose a Drawing Color");

    Button btnWH = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnWhite);
    Button btnBL = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnBlack);
    Button btnBLU = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnBlue);
    Button btnCY = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnCyan);
    Button btnDG = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnDkGray);
    Button btnGR = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnGray);
    Button btnGRE = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnGreen);
    Button btnLG = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnLtGray);
    Button btnMG = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnMagenta);
    Button btnRD = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnRed);
    Button btnYE = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnYellow);

    if (btnWH != null) {
        btnWH.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                view.paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
    if (btnBL != null) {
        btnBL.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                view.paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
    if (btnBLU != null) {
        btnBLU.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                view.paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
    if (btnCY != null) {
        btnCY.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                view.paint.setColor(Color.CYAN);
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
    if (btnDG != null) {
        btnDG.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                view.paint.setColor(Color.DKGRAY);
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
    if (btnGR != null) {
        btnGR.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                view.paint.setColor(Color.GRAY);
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
    if (btnGRE != null) {
        btnGRE.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                view.paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
    if (btnLG != null) {
        btnLG.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                view.paint.setColor(Color.LTGRAY);
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
    if (btnMG != null) {
        btnMG.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                view.paint.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
    if (btnRD != null) {
        btnRD.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                view.paint.setColor(Color.RED);
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
    if (btnYE != null) {
        btnYE.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                view.paint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
    dialog.show();
}
```

Everything is working fine except everytime I choose a new color, anything that was drawn previously also changes to the newly chosen color. How do I keep whatever was drawn previously unchanged no matter what new color is chosen next?

Comment: In the onDraw function can you try setting canvas = new Canvas();

Comment: Didn't work. It doesnt even start the Draw method.

Comment: You are changing the colour, but then redrawing everything. What you need to do is store what has been drawn already, seperately. Then copy it back each time, with additions drawn on top.

Comment: Why did you delete your previous question right after posting it? I was answering it...

Comment: It was useless question it seemed and no one answered so didn't want to keep it up :/ What is your answer if I may ask :)... Wait which question? lol

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're adding to a single path with each TouchEvent.  Then the Path is drawn using the current value of the Paint's color.  That's why you are seeing everything drawing in a single color.
You would need to create a separate Path and color for each color change and then draw them in sequence, changing the Paint's color for each drawPath() call

I don't think so.  It's not that bad to break out the paths.

```
List<Pair<Path, Integer>> path_color_list = new ArrayList<Pair<Path,Integer>>()
```

then each time you change the color.  Take the current path and view.paint.getColor and save it to your list.

```
path_color_list.add( new Pair.create(path, view.paint.getColor());
path = new Path();
```

then in your draw() iterate through the path_color_list, setting the new paint color each time

```
for (Pair<Path,Integer> path_clr : path_color_list ){
   paint.setColor(path_clr.second);
  canvas.drawPath( path_clr.first, paint);
}
```

followed with the last drawPath() that you have

Comment: Would Canvas = new Canvas(); do the trick as the other use mentioned?

Comment: I don't think so.  It's not that bad to break out the paths.

Comment: My app is FC. Should I be modifying my Paint class?

Answer (score 3):

Just do one thing always create new instance of your `view` class  `view1.paint.setColor(Color.LTGRAY);`,
then `layout.addView(view1);` means create new view it will save prevoius one also,
its work for me.   Very simple!!