# Android: How to change already drawn line color on canvas

Tags: android

I have a custom layout to draw a line based on touch input. if user draw a line with color red after draw line he want to change color. I'm trying but for that user need to draw another line then we can change color

Please anyone help me for this.

Comment: I think you have to invalidate and re draw with another color.

Comment: Thanks Malith, i tried that but its nor working

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18521661/change-color-without-affecting-anything-previously-drawn

Comment: I got the solution Thanks Jinesh.